# Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, electron

I am writing an Electron application and would like to integrate my AI. For this I have installed @tensorflow/tfjs-node version 3.0.0. When I want to execute my code (const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");) the following error message appears in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path: C:\...\simplePhishNew\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v6\tfjs_binding.node. 
Please run command 'npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node build-addon-from-source' to rebuild the native addon module.
```

The Console is tell me:
node-pre-gyp info This Node instance does not support builds for N-API version 7

The Solution,
Please run command 'npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node build-addon-from-source' to rebuild the native addon module.
doesnt work and is showing the following error message.

```
CPU-windows-3.0.0.zip
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
symlink ./lib/napi-v7 failed:  null
@tensorflow/tfjs-node@3.0.0 C:\...\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
```

Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it guys...

Step 1:
Stop crying

Step 2:
Call the boss again and take back the notice of termination

Step 3:
Electron need a specific node version
https://github.com/electron/releases
For example Electron v. 11.3.0 needs node 12.18.3

Step 4:
Ask yourself why you actually got the job